# ODP .NET Getting a SYSREFCURSOR output. {"Unsupported column datatype"} error

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, sys-refcursor

I am trying to execute a procedure that returns a stored procedure. My version of Oracle DB is 9.2 and the ODP .NET version is 10.2.0.100

My C# code looks like this.

```
OracleCommand od = new OracleCommand();
od.Connection = oc;
OracleParameter opBranchNo;
OracleParameter opSysRef;
od.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
od.CommandText = "pkg_fetchleaseinfo.proc_fetchleaseheader";

opBranchNo = new OracleParameter("IBRANCH_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 3, "044");
opBranchNo.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
od.Parameters.Add(opBranchNo);

opSysRef = new OracleParameter();
opSysRef.ParameterName = "REC_SET";
opSysRef.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
opSysRef.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
od.Parameters.Add(opSysRef);
od.Prepare();
od.ExecuteNonQuery();
Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor sysref = 
    (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor)opSysRef.Value;
return sysref.GetDataReader();
//OracleDataReader dr1 = 
//((Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor)opSysRef.Value).GetDataReader();
//return dr1;
```

My Oracle Procedure code looks like this

```
PROCEDURE proc_fetchleaseheader(ibranch_id IN VARCHAR2,
    rec_set OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS x_rec genericCursor; 
BEGIN
   OPEN x_rec FOR SELECT getleaseheaderrows(ibranch_id) FROM dual;
   rec_set := x_rec;  
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN     
   RAISE; 
END;
```

When I execute my code, the part where I attempt a GetReader() fails with an UNSUPPORTED COLUMN DATATYPE error message.

Comment: For some reason, I have not been able to format the stored procedure code correctly.

Comment: `getleaseheaderrows(ibranch_id)` is a user-defined function.  What datatype does it return?  Does your ODP stuff work if the stored procedure calls something simpler, like `select dummy from dual`?

Comment: getleaseheaderrows(ibranch_id) is a function that returns a REF CURSOR. If I try with SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL;
the function throws an error that looks like this.
Error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of
an object.

Comment: I have been able to fix that NullReferenceException. I was executing ExecuteReader(). I changed that code to ExecuteNonQuery().
I am able to successfully retrieve the value from SYSREFCURSOR with a SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are opening a refCursor to hold a Select [RefCursor] from dual

why don't you just

```
PROCEDURE proc_fetchleaseheader(ibranch_id IN VARCHAR2,
    rec_set OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS x_rec genericCursor; 
BEGIN
   x_rec := getleaseheaderrows(ibranch_id);
   rec_set := x_rec;  
/**EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN     --no need for this, the proc will raise just fine without being explicitly told to do so
   RAISE; 
***/
END;
```

or better yet just call getleaseheaderrows from the .net side and drop the procedure (just remember for parameters in ODP it *always* expects the function return value as the first param.

Comment: Do you know if things will change when we move to a PIPELINED function?